# Django template comparing string

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm new with django. I'm stuck with the problem of comparing string in the template.

I have use ifnotequal tag to compare string. But it is not working.

I have try to output the variable:

```
{{ request.user.username }} 
{{ article.creator }}
```

Here I compare:

```
{% ifnotequal request.user.username article.creator %}
    {# output something #}
{% endifnotequal %}
```

But when I do the hardcode: It works.

```
{% ifnotequal "justin" "mckoy" %}
    {# output something #}
{% endifnotequal %}
```

what is the problem? The `article.creator` is coming from the database and the `user.username` is from the request.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Could this be caused by the request.user.name is actually empty or null?
Have you checked that it really contains something?

Comment: `article.creator` is a string too?  
Can you post the model?

Comment: Also, in your example it's `request.user.usname` not `request.user.username`. Typo?

Comment: @Yuri - typo error on my example..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`article.creator` is a `User` and `request.user.username` is a string. Try comparing `request.user` instead.

Comment: When two things are not equal in Django templates, it's often the types of the variables. It happens several times that I tried to compare 1 and "1".

Comment: it will also work if `article.creator.username` compare to `request.user.username`

Comment: Only because that field happens to be unique. You should compare the models directly to be sure that they really are the same record.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams How should I do that? because this doesn't seem to work: `{% if article.creator is request.user %}`

Answer (score 82):

For string compare in template use

```
{% if name == "someone" %}
   ............
   ............
{% endif %}
```

and for not equal

```
{% if name != "someone" %}
   ............
   ............
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Use this instead of ifequal/ifnotequal, as those methods will be removed at some point in the near future. Refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#ifequal-and-ifnotequal

Comment: I am getting an error with this comparison statement

Comment: Not working for me too. I am doing `{% if utype == "p" %}`. Its just ignoring that line. Anyone got a solution?

Comment: Note that if you do not put spaces before and after `==`, Django could not parse the expression.

Answer (score 70):

Try this:

```
{% ifnotequal article.creator|stringformat:"s" request.user.username %}
```

Comment: It prints like a string, but it is not a string -- valid for UUIDs as well.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was trying to filter a variable that was surrounded by a lot of whitespace and this was the solution

Comment: This is also useful when dealing with the regroup template tag, e.g. you must use something like {% if term.grouper|stringformat:"s" == current_term.description %}

Comment: Bravo bravo, It was a nice one for me

Comment: This is deprecated now

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. I am using Django 3.0.0 and it still works.

Comment: Django documentation has been calling this depreciated since 2.0. Actually in 4.0 documentation it is no longer present. So no, this is not the correct answer (anymore).

Answer (score 6):

```
{% ifequal material.unit 'U' %}
    <p>are equals!<p/>
{% endifequal %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you do not put spaces before and after ==, Django could not parse the expression.

```
{% if MyProd.Status == "Processing" %}
       <button class="btn btn-outline-warning">{{MyProd.Status}}</button>
{% else %}
       <button class="btn btn-outline-success">{{MyProd.Status}}</button>
{% endif %}
```